# Retrieving the value of a setInterval jQuery

Tags: jquery, variables, setinterval

Is it possible to retrieve the value of a setInterval in jQuery?

Example: in the code I declare

```
setInterval(email, 10000);
```

Can I get back that `10000` and put it to a variable?

Comment: No. But you could put it into a variable beforehand and use it in both places.

Comment: You may use a timer. Just start it somewhere and stop it when your setInterval gets executed. You may get the approximated correct value (in your case 10000).

Comment: thanks that anwser my question

Comment: In that case I added it as an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I get back that `10000` and put it to a variable?

No. But you could put it into a variable beforehand and use it in both places, something like this:

```
var interval = 10000;

setInterval(email, interval);
doSomethingElse(interval);
```